# Test C++ poll socket function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, sockets

I'm writing a bunch of tests for a function that we have to check if a socket is ready to read. We are using the function poll http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html .

The problem we are facing is emulating some sockets states, like waiting for a timeout, socket error and so on.

We have a very simple function defined like this

```
bool wait_for_socket_data(int fd, int timeout_millisecs) {
  if (fd < 0 or timeout_millisecs < 0)
    return false;

  struct pollfd fds[1];

  fds[0].fd = fd;
  fds[0].events = POLLIN;

  const int poll_response = poll(fds, sizeof(fds)/sizeof(struct pollfd), timeout_millisecs);

  std::cout << poll_response;

  if (poll_response <= 0)
    return false;

 //here we will check different values in event inside struct 
  return true;
}
```

We create in our test function a socket like this:

```
  const int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
  memcpy(&addr.sin6_addr, &in6addr_any, sizeof(in6addr_any));
  addr.sin6_port = htons(server_port);

  const int rc = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

The problem is calling poll which always returns a value > 0. We are trying to test getting the 0 case, which is a timeout, and the negative one which is an error. We have tried to mock this but we can't as it's not inside a class to inherit from and create a mock or use GMock framework. Creating a class only for this method is excessive. Can we emulate these different sockets states in any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

poll is marked as *weak* symbol in libc so you could define your own stub'ed poll and after dynamic linking your application will use the stub.

Something like this:

```
TestState g_test = TestState::Uninitialized;
void test2() {
   ....
   g_test = TestState::TestTimeout;
   ....
   poll();
}
int poll (struct pollfd *__fds, nfds_t __nfds, int __timeout) {
    switch (g_test) {
        case TestState::TestTimeout:
            return 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you very much!